# Change recylcerview item's ui on button click from another activity in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview as shown below. When I click on the "Invite to job" button it opens up another activity which has a button. And on that button click I want to disable the selected item's button and change its text to "Invited". :

[image]

This is what I tried. I passed a boolean using the shared preferences when the button from another activity is  clicked.

```
 sharedPref.putBoolean(Constants.CHANGE_INVITE_BUTTON, true)
```

And then in the recyclerview's adapter I added this inside onBindViewHolder :

```
 if(sharedPref.getBoolean(Constants.CHANGE_INVITE_BUTTON,true)){
                holder.binding.inviteToJobButtonFreelancerScreenCu.isEnabled = false
                holder.binding.inviteToJobButtonFreelancerScreenCu.text = "Invited"
            }

            else{
                holder.binding.inviteToJobButtonFreelancerScreenCu.setOnClickListener {
                    freelancersFragmentCu.onItemClicked(freelancerFilterList[position])

                }
            }
```

If the value is true then just change the text and disable the button but if it's not then continue to open the activity with that button. But now when I run it all the buttons are disabled and their texts have changed, so it is not working properly at all.

Comment: your question is confusing at one part you say it's working and at one part it's not please explain it properly!

Comment: The bottom line is that it isn't working properly. It changes all the button's text and disables them when i run the app. Which i dont want.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you're trying to map all recycler view items with a single sharedprefs value each recycler items have individual id, hence to solve this you need to put an extra int value with your sharedprefs

Whenever you do `sharedPref.putBoolean(Constants.CHANGE_INVITE_BUTTON, true)`
Instead of using `Constants.CHANGE_INVITE_BUTTON` change it to holder item value.

```
sharedPref.putBoolean(holder.binding.inviteToJobButtonFreelancerScreenCu.id, true)
```

Thereafter, change your if condition to this:

```
if(sharedPref.getBoolean(holder.binding.inviteToJobButtonFreelancerScreenCu.id,true))
```

Hence after this whenever your adapter is updated only the item id which is having true will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on `Invite Job` Button you need to take one boolean variable that indicates you invite for that particular job or not in your model which you bind in your `RecyclerView`. And by default that boolean id false for all Jobs.

Once you click on Invite Job Button then you need to do that `Boolean` as `true` and notify your `Adapter`.

Text change and disable button you need to do based on your `Boolean`.